# css and html section structure issues

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage I need help restructuring. Each section in this html webpage uses the `<section>` tag. The issue I am having is getting each `<section>` tag to span the full width using css. For example, on stackoverflow there is obviously a header `<section>` tag, body `section` tag and a footer `<section>` tag. The header and footer both have background colors and span the full width of the page (no whitespace). I know css frameworks like bootstrap achieve this stuff, but I wanna know how do I achieve this using html and css without having to use a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this ?

[image: Want something like this]

Comment: Perfect! If I add extra sections like a body and a footer, use the same setup and it will fall into place?

Comment: you couldn't imagine the types of hacks I've had to use in the past to achieve this lol

Comment: Lol. Programming Rule#1: Never forgets your past hacks.

Comment: It resets whole body. Now you just need to play with body and footer. It will fall into place as you want. And if that answer helps you so please check it for correct answer and help me getting some reputation

Comment: most deff, thanks bro. you got codepen link by chance?

Comment: Nope, Currently at office so back to home will make it definitely